# How do I apply coupon code calculation in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to create a 10% price reduction coupon in my form.  I have followed the instructions carefully, using a Price Field named Discount.

Two questions.  First, when I input the given code "CouponCode = "Save10" ? -ItemTotal*0.1 : 0"  into the Amount field it refuses to accept with an error code "Calculation must be formatted as $#,###.##."  So it won't accept this calculation because it has text!?!

Also if there is a way to get this to do what the developers say it will do, how do i get it to take 10% off of the Payment Total?  Do I have to enter all the concerned fields or will the input "ItemTotal" catch the whole form?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to enter the code into generated form which allows for submission

[image]

That's not quite correct - you need to enter the code for calculation when you're *building* the form - once you add the Price field, on the builder, look for an Amount field on the left side and enter the code there

[image: From form builder]

You'll see that once you do this, it will calculate correctly.

[image]

Comment: Also, please note that calculations must start with an "=".  Otherwise, [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) will assume you are trying to enter a constant value, not a calculation.